# how to gzip files in tmp folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip, gzip, tmp

Using an AWS Lambda function, I download an S3 zipped file and unzip it.

For now I do it using `extractall`. Upon unzipping, all files are saved in the `tmp/` folder.

```
s3.download_file('test','10000838.zip','/tmp/10000838.zip')

with zipfile.ZipFile('/tmp/10000838.zip', 'r') as zip_ref:
    lstNEW = list(filter(lambda x: not x.startswith("__MACOSX/"), zip_ref.namelist()))
    zip_ref.extractall('/tmp/', members=lstNEW)
```

After unzipping, I want to gzip files and place them in another S3 bucket.

Now, how can I read all files from the `tmp` folder again and gzip each file?
`$item.csv.gz`

I see this (https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html) but I am not sure which function is to be used.

If it's the compress function, how exactly do I use it? I read in this answer [gzip a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156707/gzip-a-file-in-python) that I can use the open function `gzip.open('', 'wb')` to gzip a file but I couldn't figure out how to use it in my case. In the open function, do I specify the target location or the source location? Where do I save the gzipped files such as that I can later save them to S3?

**Alternative Option:**

Instead of loading everything into the `tmp` folder,  I read that I can also open an output stream, wrap the output stream in a gzip wrapper, and then copy from one stream to the other

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('/tmp/10000838.zip', 'r') as zip_ref:
    testList = []
    for i in zip_ref.namelist():
        if (i.startswith("__MACOSX/") == False):
            testList.append(i)
    for i in testList:
        zip_ref.open(i, ‘r’)
```

but then again I am not sure how to continue in the for loop and open the stream and convert files there

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the sizes of the files, I would skip writing the .gz file(s) to disk. Perhaps something based on `s3fs` | `boto` and `gzip`.

```
import contextlib
import gzip

import s3fs

AWS_S3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False) # AWS env must be set up correctly

source_file_path = "/tmp/your_file.txt"
s3_file_path = "my-bucket/your_file.txt.gz"

with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
    source_file = stack.enter_context(open(source_file_path , mode="rb"))
    destination_file = stack.enter_context(AWS_S3.open(s3_file_path, mode="wb"))
    destination_file_gz = stack.enter_context(gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=destination_file))
    while True:
        chunk = source_file.read(1024)
        if not chunk:
            break
        destination_file_gz.write(chunk)
```

Note: I have not tested this so if it does not work, let me know.